# Stopping a function when a certain condition is met and starting it again on other condition

Tags: javascript, jquery, return

I've a checkbox (kinda switch button) to turn a functionality ON/OFF. When i turn it ON, function should work and when I turn it OFF, the function should not work.
Now the problem is when i turn the switch ON, run the function and turn it back OFF, the function is still working and is not stopping. I need to stop the function from working when the switch is OFF. I've made a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tusharshuklaa/uu1807z4/18/)  too of my problem.
HTML Structure:

```
<label for="onoffswitch">Switch: </label>
<input type="checkbox" name="onoffswitch" class="onoffswitch-checkbox" id="mathswitch">
<br><br>
<textarea name="question1" id="question1" class="question_aptitude maths_editor"></textarea>
<br><br>
<div id="result"></div>
```

JS:

```
var isMaths=0;
$(function(){
    $("#mathswitch").on('click', function(e){
        chk= $("#mathswitch:checked").length;     
        if (chk>0)
        {
            isMaths=1;
        }
        else
        {
            isMaths=0;
        }
        e.stopImmediatePropagation();
    })

    $(".maths_editor").focus(function(){
        store_id= $(this).prop('id');
        console.log("chk :" + chk);
        if (isMaths=='1')
        {
           myfunction();
        }
        else
        {
          $('#'+store_id).on('keyup', function (e){
            var key = e.keyCode;
            if (key == 77 && e.altKey)
            {
                alert("Maths is turned OFF");
                e.stopImmediatePropagation();
                return;
            }
            if (key == 90 && e.altKey)
            {
                alert("Maths is turned OFF");
                e.stopImmediatePropagation();
                return;
            }
          })
        }
    })
})
function myfunction() {
    $("#result").text("Maths is ON!");
  console.log("working!");
  $('#'+store_id).on('keyup', function (e){
    var key = e.keyCode;
    if (key == 77 && e.altKey)
    {
        alert("Maths is turned ON");
        e.stopImmediatePropagation();
        return;
    }
    if (key == 90 && e.altKey)
    {
        alert("Maths is turned ON");
        e.stopImmediatePropagation();
        return;
    }
  })
}
```

I've googled about stopping a function and most of them said to use `return` but that doesn't seem to work in my case.

Comment: That was the first thing i tried but it doesn't work for me in this case :p

Comment: why are you using click on checkbox, it will always give you previous state of cb, try change event, and check condition should be $("#mathswitch").is('checked')

Comment: So on uncheck - what you actually need ?

Comment: @A.T. Ok, i'll try that

Comment: @Rigin I want that `myFunction()` should not work when cb is unchecked!!

Comment: @TusharShukla Cant you give a check inside this myFunction() - that if(cb.checked) - then Do, Else - Dont Do.

Comment: @Rigin No, actually myFunction() here is actually for demo purpose, originally this function is in a different JS file which is being called on many other pages. I can't make changes to that file considering ONE condition for this page only!

Comment: hehe, Ok - So you want in cb unchecked case - the function to disppear

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102434/discussion-between-rigin-and-tushar-shukla).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use jQuery .off() to remove the keyup event handler and declare a new one on focus according to the checkbox. [See the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/off/)

```js
$(function(){
    $(".maths_editor").focus(function(){
     $(this).off("keyup");
        store_id= $(this).prop('id');
        if ($("#mathswitch").is(":checked"))
        {
           myfunction();
        }
        else
        {
          $('#'+store_id).on('keyup', function (e){
            var key = e.keyCode;
            if (key == 77 && e.altKey)
            {
                alert("Maths is turned OFF");
                e.stopImmediatePropagation();
                return;
            }
            if (key == 90 && e.altKey)
            {
                alert("Maths is turned OFF");
                e.stopImmediatePropagation();
                return;
            }
          });
        }
    });
});

function myfunction() {
  $('#'+store_id).on('keyup', function (e){
    var key = e.keyCode;
    if (key == 77 && e.altKey)
    {
        alert("Maths is turned ON");
        e.stopImmediatePropagation();
        return;
    }
    if (key == 90 && e.altKey)
    {
        alert("Maths is turned ON");
        e.stopImmediatePropagation();
        return;
    }
  });
}
```

```css
.case{
  width: 40%;
  float: right;
  border: 1px solid;
  padding: 0.5em;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="case">
<h3>
Cases
</h3>
Please use CONSOLE to see values<br><br>
Case1: Initially without checking the checkbox and typing in the textbox, Pressing Alt+M should give alert ""Maths is OFF" but its not doing so!!<br><br>
Case2: After going through Case1, now check the checkbox and press Alt+M in texbox. It works fine. Now uncheck the checkbox and type Alt+m again. I still get the alert "Maths is ON" whereas i'm expecting it not to work because IF statement is false now!
</div>
<label for="onoffswitch">Switch: </label>
<input type="checkbox" name="onoffswitch" class="onoffswitch-checkbox" id="mathswitch">
<br><br>
<textarea name="question1" id="question1" class="question_aptitude maths_editor" wrap="hard"></textarea>
<br><br>
<div id="result">

</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it worked as expected! Also, this is the cleanest solution to me.

Answer (score 2):

I've modified your javascript to get the functionality that I believe you're wanting, [here's the fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jghvtfs9/).

The main issue is that you were adding a keyup event everytime the editor was focused or when myFunction ran, and you were also trying to log the chk variable in a scope where it couldn't be logged. My modifications change the core aspect of you wanting it to "turn a *function* on or off" but I feel that it may work for what you need it for. If you need me to explain anything feel free to comment!

Here's the code:

```
var isMaths = false;

$(function() {
    $("#mathswitch").on('click', function(e) {
        isMaths = $("#mathswitch").prop('checked');

        e.stopImmediatePropagation();
    })

    $('.maths_editor').on('keyup', myfunction);
})

function myfunction(e) {
    var key = e.keyCode;

    if (isMaths) {
        $("#result").text("Maths is ON!");
        console.log("working!");

        // Here is where you would call the function that's in an
        // external file as you said in the comments on your question.
        externalFileFunctionCall();

        if (key == 77 && e.altKey) {
            alert("Maths is turned ON");
            e.stopImmediatePropagation();
            return;
        }
        if (key == 90 && e.altKey) {
            alert("Maths is turned ON");
            e.stopImmediatePropagation();
            return;
        }
    } else {
        $("#result").text("Maths is OFF!");

        if (key == 77 && e.altKey) {
            alert("Maths is turned OFF");
            e.stopImmediatePropagation();
            return;
        }
        if (key == 90 && e.altKey) {
            alert("Maths is turned OFF");
            e.stopImmediatePropagation();
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your code and time. It is working as expected. But as i mentioned in a comment above, i'm not allowed to make changes in myFunction(). This `myFunction();` is a part of a different JS file and that JS file is being used on many other pages hence i cannot make changes to that file considering only one condition meant for this page only.

Comment: I noticed that! I added a comment to the code to show where you could call that function at.

Comment: `myFunction()` itself is in a different JS file. I added this myFunction here just for illustrating the issue. I cannot change myFunction()

Comment: Yes I understand, if you look at the code you will see where I have added comments where you would run that function. In my example I named the function "externalFileFunctionCall();". No modifications need to be made to it, you just simply rename it and call it where it is located in the code.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your code, it did work fine. I had to do headbanging for a while to understand that `myFunction()` that you have mentioned in your code is different from what i was expecting it to be.